# How can I correctly format file reference for HTML5 Audio element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-audio

I'm using the HTML5 `<audio>` element in a Node.js app and I'm running in to problems with the file references and special characters when setting the `src.track`. When referencing the file location from my mySQLite3 database, I'll send a location formatted as:

```
/Users/admin/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Nelly/Nellyville/13 #1.mp3
```

I get the following error:

```
GET file:///Users/admin/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Nelly/Nellyville/13%20 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It is obviously erroring out on the "#" in this particular string and ignoring the remainder of the string. This formatting works for all references except for those with special characters. I've tried every type of encoding, escaping, and formatting I can think of including `encodeURIComponent()` and `encodeURI()`.

I can output a string in javascript using `encodeURIComponent()` which produces a working link that I can paste in my browser to correctly reference the file. However, if I set my `track.src` using the output from `encodeURIComponent()`, it adds my project directory on to the string and errors out as so:

```
GET file:///Users/admin/Code/project/src/%2FUsers%2Fadmin%2FMusic%2FiTunes%2FiTunes%20Music%2FNelly%2FNellyville%2F13%20%231.mp3 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: It’s failing because you can’t use `file://` URIs in web-pages unless the page itself is also loaded from a `file://` URI. As you’re using a NodeJS server that I assume is on `localhost` you’ll need to proxy those files through NodeJS too. Watch out for directory traversal attacks.

Comment: @Dai It's an Electron app, so it would be loading the webpage from the same local project directory. I am passing the string without `file://`, I'm just passing the raw directory path, as indicated above, then I'm guessing the `audio` element is doing some sort of URI encoding and adding the `file://`. If I don't URI encode, it can't resolve the path, if I do, the above happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after probably 100 different variations of `src` input in to the `<audio>` element, I determined that, at least in my Electron app, it uses some sort of hybrid between `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`. `encodeURIComponent` encodes the "/" which will not work, but `encodeURI` does not encode the characters which were causing the problem, such as "#". So, here is the way I've figured out how to make this work:

```
function URLFormat(input){
    let URIencodedURL = encodeURIComponent(input);
    let EncodedURL = 'file:///' + URIencodedURL.replaceAll("%2F","/");
    return EncodedURL;
}
```

This provides me with a proper input path for the `<audio>` element even in the case of files with special characters.